# How to get sub domain on gcp instance running gitlab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, google-compute-engine, hosting

I have installed gitlab on a gcp debian vm instance. Now I have a domain name lets say xyz.com that is hosted on a different shared hosting platform which has my personal website. Now I want to add gitlab.xyz.com to my gcp instance. I followed the tutorial by gitlab and edited

```
/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I am new to this so, if anyone could outline the steps I need to perform then it would be really helpful.

Comment: **1.** Have you configured DNS records for your subdomain name? **2.** Does it resolve into IP of your VM instance? **3.** I'd recommend you to [reserve a static external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) for your VM instance.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza Thanks, I reserved the static ip and the problem was fixed. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To solve your issue** you should [reserve a static external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) for your VM instance and configure DNS record for your subdomain.